# Spring boot & React production build

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, build

I created a spring boot project.After that,I created react project on spring boot project.Right now,both frontend and backend server are running.On frontend folder,I    run that command `npm run build`.

It created a folder which is called build.What I want to do is to run all project with one server.(Example: localhost:8080).I know that I should move frontend files to under static folder.How do I do this?

I tried maven-antrun-plugin but it is not working.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build"/>
                            </copy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the maven [copy resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)

Comment: Right now, under resource/static, I created react project.Then, I created build folder with 'npm run build'.Right now when I run project again,I see WhiteLabel Error.Do I have to use copy resource plugin?